# Can't access inherited method outside of the class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a window in gtk. Here is my code:

```
require 'gtk3'

class Win < Gtk::Window
    include Gtk
    def initialize
        super
        set_title "RubyCalculator"
        set_default_geometry 300 , 300
        #show      show works here fine
    end

end

Win.new
Win.show # I get error here
Gtk.main
```

I can't access an inherited method outside of the class. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
./Main.rb:19:in `<main>': undefined method `show' for Win:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: check the documentation of Gtk. I don't see a `show` method there. it is available for Gtk::Widget. if you find one, make sure whether it is a class method or instance method

Comment: ah! I found your mistake

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window = Win.new
window.show
```

You should call the show method on the instance you created. Not on the class itself